# Create xml in oracle

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables:

1. table 1: xml seq, XML start TAGS ,XML end TAGS  database column name , default value
2. table 2: table with column  value.

How to  create XML using both the tables if no value in another table.
Logic:

cursor xmlstart tag || NVL(read column name from table 1 and fetch data from table 2 for the column name stored in table 1, default value||XML end TAGS
order by xml seq

Comment: Not clear what do you want. Give some sample dataset and expected result

Comment: Maybe, you need SQL/XML?

Comment: In one table I stored all my xml tags and database  column name 
I want to change values in xml table if my column has some value
Ex
Table 1
Xml rag      default value    database column name
X1                125                        invamount
X2                 INR                       currency
X3                dgg                        docno

Table2
Invamount  currency    doc no
1250              USD            xvbjhgf


Xml
<x1>nvl (1250,125)</x1>
<x2>nvl (USD, inr)<x2>

How to do with oracle query

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include more details. Code is extremely hard to read in comments.